# Serve html file with custom status code

Tags: go, http-status-code-404

I need to have a custom not found html page. Here is what I've tried:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func main() {
    r := httprouter.New()

    r.NotFound = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "files/not-found.html")
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}
```

I have the line `w.WriteHeader(404)` to make sure the status code is 404, but the code above gives the error:

> http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Without the line `w.WriteHeader(404)` there are no errors and the page is shown correctly, but the status code is 200. I want it to be 404.

Comment: one way around is to mock w so it does not allow to change the status code to 200 when passed to http.servefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David's answer worked, and this is another way.

```
// other header stuff
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
file, err := os.Open("files/not-found.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
_, err = io.Copy(w, file)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
file.Close() // consider defer ^
```

Comment: defer file.Close

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just write the contents yourself.

Something like:

```
r.NotFound = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadFile("files/not-found.html")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err) // or do something useful
        }
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        w.Write(contents)
    })
```

Comment: I considered that. Would there be a more memory-efficient way to do this with io.Copy?

Comment: Most likely, yes.  Is your 404 page big enough to worry about memory efficiency?

Comment: If the 404 page was really, really small, could ioutil.ReadFile work faster than io.Copy?

Comment: if you wanted faster, I'd probably just load the content in to a slice at start time and just write it each time.   No reason to load from disk every time and the 404 page is probably not something you'd need to change "live" in the server.